# pycharm doesnt recognize pycryptodome

Tags: python

Hi I need to cipher a code using AES for that I installed pycryptodome (as far as I understood the crypto libary is already outdated and its better to use pycryptodome)
however its  seems like pycharm doesn't find the libary i tried to install both with pip install and through the pycharm itself
[image: can't find Crypto]

and as you can see pycryptodome is installed on pycharm:
[image: pycryptodome is installed]

Comment: Does the script run?  It looks like that's just an editor whining at you.  Editors are not always smart enough.

Comment: No the script doesn't run  and gives the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'" (wtithout  the import the  script runs fine so the problem is  in the 
 import)

Comment: Do you have multiple interpreters? What happens if you try to import the package from the Python Console window?

Comment: I had IDLE  installed i removed it and installed new  version  of  python at  first  didnt  look like it did something but after I also added  test vectors for pycryptodom it look like its working at least for now